# Splitting a circular linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

So I got a question in data structures assignment earlier this week. The question was to split a circularly linked list into two halves, with elements at the even positions in one list and the one at odd positions in another.This is the logic I tried out.

```
temp= p1 = front;
p2= front->next;
do
 {p1->next = temp->next->next;
  p1= temp->next->next;
  p2->next = temp->next->next->next;
  p2= temp->next->next->next;
  temp=temp->next;
 } while (temp!= front);
p1->next=p1;
p2->next=p2;
```

My logic was to create two pointers , one pointing to the first element and one to the next. Then I traverse the lists from one end to the other. While I do so, I set the next pointer of each to point to elements at the alternate positions.
Note that p1, p2, front, temp and next are point of struct Node
which is defined as this

```
  typedef struct 
  {
   type element;
   Node* next;
  }Node;
```

However my professor marked my answer as incorrect without any explanation. Can someone tell me why this was wrong?

Comment: Have you tested your logic for 2 nodes or 3 nodes circular linked list? The main problem in your logic is `temp=temp->next;`. The P1 and P2 are moving down the list from there current position to `next->next` position but temp is moving to its `next`.

Comment: I was using temp to traverse the original circular linked list, so that I can refer to the original list's elements.

Comment: Create two new lists, 'newListOdd' and 'newListEven'.  Loop round 'if (pop(oldList)) push(newListOdd) else break;if (pop(oldList)) push(newListEven) else break;'  Then destroy the old list.  Done, easy.

Comment: Do you realise that  `p1->next=p1;` creates a *very short* cyclic linked list?

Comment: I got that. I didn't make the same mistake in my original answer, I had saved the head of each list in a separate variable to be referenced in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose at first `temp` points to a odd postion ,so `p1` points to odd and `p2` points to even element but after first `temp=temp->next` temp points to a even element and when you assign `p1` as `p1-temp->next->next` which is an even elements and now `p2` will points to an odd position element.And in each alternate iteration `p1` will points to even position and in other even position , so does `p2`.